# react fetch usestate not iterate

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

HOME page:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Main} from './style'
import {sendRequest}  from './ajax/main'



const Home:React.FC<any> = () =>{
  const [state = {data: []}, setState] = useState<any>([])
  const getResult = async() => {
    let response:any = await sendRequest('POST','http://127.0.0.1:5500/api/home')
    setState({ data: [response] })
  }
  useEffect(()=>{ getResult() }, [])
return (<Main>
    {state.data.map((item:any) => (
      <img key={item.id} src={item.picture} alt={item.show_name} />
    ))}
</Main>)}

export default Home;
```

ajax components:

```
const headers = {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
export function sendRequest(method:string, url:string, body = null){
  fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: headers
   }).then(response => response.json())
     .then(result  => result)
}
```

Why can't I iterate the answer we get? Where is the mistake?

Comment: You've defined your state all wrong, move the `data: []` into the state declaration, i.e. `const [state, setState] = useState<any>({ data: [] })` Since you are declaring the state there's no need for the fallback, React won't steer you wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is at this line -
`const [state = {data: []}, setState] = useState<any>([])`

useState is injecting a default state `[]` to 'state' constant variable.
However, you are trying to de-structure and set the fallback value to be `{ data: [] }`. That is the reason why state.data.map is undefined as state contains empty array.

Resolution -
`const [state = {data: []}, setState] = useState<any>({data: []})`